# Wordpress File and Another Extra Folders

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, directory-structure

I need to import a Huge website of over 3000 pages
the old content have image or pdf resources everywhere and over 120 static pages.

so some resource can be in `/im/foldername/anotherfolder/` others can be `/foldername/` obviously I can't rewrite every single url so I have all folders that contains resources sitting inside the same wordpress directory

```
/root/
    /wp-admin/
    /wp-content/
    /wp-includes/
    /im/
    /video/
    /about/
    /pdfs/
    /education/
```

Here is an example of the the site folders.. the resources will have their old paths but I do not want the path `www.example.com/education/` to end up in the folder, but instead actually go to the wordpress.

would I have to put a htaccess on every folder or something? how would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a bad decision for structure . and it is bad on many levels .
In WordPress, you will want all the files that do not belong to `CORE` to reside in one folder, and one only, and that is the `wp-content` .

Any other structure might look easier for you to implement , but it is almost guaranteed to create more problems in the future , including security problems ...
Further more , if you will make new uploads in that site , you will have duplicate areas with external files .

What you need is to put all those folders inside `wp-content` and then just change the relative URL .

You did not mention how the URL´s are coded , are they in a special table or part of posts , or just coded in theme , but anyhow , there are several things you can do .

If your urls are coded in the them use [wp_upload_dir()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url) or [wp_content_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_ur) or any other related directory structure functions ( see related at bottom on linked codex pages ) . Using this let you easily control the URLs

```
$mydir = wp_upload_dir() . '/my_dir/video/'// etc.. etc..
```

If your Urls are in DB , or posts for example , you can do something like this :

```
UPDATE wp_newsite_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_path/multi', 'wp-content/etc/etc/');
```

Of course that you will first need to decide where and how you are using those .

Another thing you could do would be to change the `upload_dir` constants in `wp-config`

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/somedir');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/somedir');
```

This method is not really reccomended if you do not know or fully understand what you are doing . [more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants)

Now , because your question lacks in specific , i might not have understood it - but it is more likely that either :

1. You are looking for the easy way ( `!=` the correct way )
2. you do not fully understand how wordpress process attachments and
   what they are .
3. you are not planning of using wordpress as a cms , no updating of
   files or new content ( in which case it is not so logic to use it in
   the first place )

Comment: well Thanks for the break downs.. I was mostly looking for an easy way out. the old content contains about 2500 database posts and with really old database structure and the rest are all static html that I have already crawled and imported into wordpress cms so now everything is in wordpress but the content area is filled with different ways of pointing to resources. `./../` or `./` or `/` or actual full paths. and those file are over thousands. The hard way is quite abit of work.

Comment: @vico . The hard way is not so hard if you use sql . I had a similar job done ( around 35,000 attachments and more than 70,000 posts ) in around an hour . But sure . you can do what you want . Just be careful on future updates ...